# Data is not displayed in TableView from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a  2 problems with displaying data in a table from Firebase.

1. Nothing displayed in TableView from Firebase
2. I I can not add a link(child) to a variable

Print is working. I get access to Firebase, but nothing is added to TableView. Please, look at my code and correct where i'm wrong.

It's my model

```
class Exercises {

    var titleExercise = ""
    var descriptionExercise = ""

    init (titleExercise: String, descriptionExercise: String) {

        self.titleExercise = titleExercise
        self.descriptionExercise = descriptionExercise
    }
}
```

It's my ViewController

```
class ExercisesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {




    //MARK: Properties
    var refWorkout: String = ""
    var workout: TrainingProgram?
    var ref: DatabaseReference!


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var exercises = [Exercises]()


    //MARK: Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchExercises()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        refWorkout = workout!.title





    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return exercises.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as!  ExercisesTableViewCell

        let workouts = exercises[indexPath.item]
        cell.titleLabel.text = workouts.titleExercise
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = workouts.descriptionExercise

        return cell
    }

    func fetchExercises() {
        Database.database().reference().child("programs").child("OPEN SPACE").child("exercises").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.value)
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let newTitle = dict["title"] as! String
                let newDescription = dict["description"] as! String
                let exerciseTableCell = Exercises(titleExercise: newTitle, descriptionExercise: newDescription)

            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }


    }


}
```

And I have **second question**. It also addresses this issue.
As you can see, I have `refWorkout = workout!.title` Here comes the title from previous ViewController , and refWorkout is a child for Firebase. If I will write next code

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("programs").child(refWorkout).child("exercises")

   ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
       print(snapshot.value)
   }
```

Everything will work. Print will work. But if I insert this code to `func fetchExercises()` - > It will look like

```
func fetchExercises() {
        Database.database().reference().child("programs").child(refWorkout).child("exercises").observe(.childAdded)...
```

My app crashed. 
Please help me with two questions. Thank you!

My Firebase structure [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake, you are reloading the table view too soon and you don't assign/append the result to the data source array

The `observe` API works asynchronously, put the line to reload the table view into the closure

```
func fetchExercises() {
    Database.database().reference().child("programs").child("OPEN SPACE").child("exercises").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.value)
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] { // most likely all values are value type
            let newTitle = dict["title"] as! String
            let newDescription = dict["description"] as! String
            let exercise = Exercises(titleExercise: newTitle, descriptionExercise: newDescription)
            self.exercises.append(exercise)

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Side note:

You class contains 3 bad practices:

1. Semantically objects used in collection types should be named in singular form.
2. Don't declare properties with default values if there is an initializer.
3. There is too much redundant information in the variable names

And in most cases a struct and even constants are sufficient. I'd recommend

```
struct Exercise {
    let title : String
    let description : String
}
```

In a struct you get the initializer for free.

Comment: It did not help :(

Comment: Then `snapshot.value` might be an array. Please add the result of `print(snapshot.value)` to the question.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you ;) And please, explain me why my second question does't work. In my first ViewController I have collectionView with titles. When user click on one of the cells user go to the next ViewController (with TableView). In my tableview I shoud display Data from Firebase, but i must know the reference which I should choose.

Comment: So, I decided to keep the reference like var. var refWorkout is my title from previous ViewController. So, I want to do next: `func fetchExercises() {
        Database.database().reference().child("programs").child(refWorkout).child("exercises").... ` But I have crash when i want to put `child(refWorkout)`

Comment: Because you call `fetchExercises` before assigning the value to `refWorkout`. Move the line `fetchExercises()` **behind** `refWorkout = workout!.title`

Comment: Thank you. Everything is working. Have a nice day ! :))